# ChartJS Realtime Animation

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to use Chart.js to create a realtime chart, but seem to be having an issue with it not animating from right to left.

The example that I am working from is this: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/KToiNLlBrQzBsO1cPDNU?p=preview
However, this is what I am getting:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kkJJZE?editors=1010

I believe I am updating the data correctly as shown here:

```
setInterval(function randomdata() {
  cpuChart.data.datasets[0].data.shift();
  cpuChart.data.labels.shift();

  var ts = new Date().getTime(), 
      csecs = moment(ts).format('s'),
      label = '';

  if (csecs % 15 === 0) {
      label = csecs == '0' ? moment(ts).format('HH:mm') : moment(ts).format(':ss');
  } 

  cpuChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1));
  cpuChart.data.labels.push(label);

  cpuChart.update();

}, 1000);
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the referred chart.js in your solution is different.

Comment: Interesting, you are correct - I saw that both versions of Chart.JS are `2.3.0` in the comments above, however, they are not identical.  Thank you for pointing that out, this resolves the headache I was facing.